# undefined error from react props component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-props

I am seriously confused and frustrated, I have a react modal component that displays user imformation I fetch from firebase. I pass the information from the parent to the modal as props and recieves it like this:

```
const AdminEdit = (props) => {
const [updatedUserState, setUpdatedUserState] = useState(props.state);
const [updatedUserCity, setUpdatedUserCity] = useState(props.city);
const [updatedUserAddress, setUpdatedUserAddress] = useState(props.address);
const [updatedUserAbout, setUpdatedUserAbout] = useState(props.about);
const [updatedUserPhone, setUpdatedUserPhone] = useState(props.phone);
const [updatedUserFullName, setUpdatedUserFullName] = useState(props.fullName);
const [updatedUserName, setUpdatedUserName] = useState(props.userName);
const [updatedUserEmail, setUpdatedUserEmail] = useState(props.email);
const [updatedUserStatus, setUpdatedUserStatus] = useState(props.status);
const [updatedUserCountry, setUpdatedUserCountry] = useState(props.country);
```

....

The issue is, when I console.log(props.fullName), I get the user full name, but when I console.log(updatedUserFullName) which is supposed to take initial value of the props.fullName gives me an undefined instead of the full name.

I am seriously confused. I have a function that update the user information:

```
const handleUpdateProfile = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Create an object with the updated user information
    const updatedUserData = {
        state: updatedUser.state,
        city: updatedUser.city,
        address: updatedUser.address,
        about: updatedUser.about,
        phone: updatedUser.phone,
        email: updatedUser.email,
        fullName: updatedUser.fullName,
        userName: updatedUser.userName,
        status: updatedUser.status,
        country: updatedUser.country

    };

    try {
        // Get a reference to the user's Firestore document
        const userDocRef = doc(collection(db, "users"), props.userUid);


        // Update the user's document in Firestore
        await updateDoc(userDocRef, updatedUserData)
```

...

Why am I getting undefined?

I passed the props from the parents like this:

```
<AdminEditDashModal
            show={editModalShow}
            onHide={() => setEditModalShow(false)}
            userUid={editUserUid}
            fullName={fullName}
            userAbout={userAbout}
            userState={userState}
            userName={userName}
            userStatus={userStatus}
            userCity={userCity}
            userCountry={userCountry}
            userAddress={userAddress}
            phone={phone}
            phone_code={phone_code}
        />
```

Comment: I assume because when the component is first mounted you haven't finished loading the user data so the initial value is undefined. You could easily check this by picking one of your state variables and adding a corresponding `useEffect` update i.e. `useEffect(() => { setUpdatedUserFullName(props.fullName); }, [props.fullName]);`. If this fixes the problem then you have your answer. Either add a `useEffect` to update each state value when the passed in props change, or don't mount the component until you have your user data.

Comment: Let me try this